# I want to open a domain content from another domain, with exactly same request url but domain name are different

Tags: .htaccess, proxy, dns, cpanel, whm

I have two domains hosted in same server with same account, I want to open a domain content from another domain, with exactly same request `url` but domain name are different.

I have cpanel as well as WHM. I have tried:-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://old.com/$1 [P]
```

but when `new.com` login is done from `old.com` redirection is going to `old.com.`

I am unable to use Apache `mod_userdir` Tweak from whm. the domain listed here but I dont know how to set up.

No luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

No need to neither `mod_proxy` nor `.htaccess` all you have to do is to configure a new domain as an alias to old domain ,so follow these steps in cpanel blog https://blog.cpanel.com/pointing-two-urls-to-the-same-website/